# How to listeTo a particular options in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, listen

I have view which is initialized as below

```
app.OfferMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: { },
    initialize: function(options) { 
        this.options = options || {};
    }
});
```

I create an instance of it along with an option -

```
this.offermenu = new app.OfferMenuView({offer_heading:-1});
```

Now I want to bind a `listenTo` to listen to the change in the value of the `options.offer_heading` .

I have tried with writing this:

```
this.offermenu.listenTo(this.offermenu,'change:options',this.offermenu.render);
```

But this does not go to `render` function on change of `offer_heading`. What is the correct way of binding a listenTo for change in an `options` value ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example:

```
app.OfferMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: { },
    initialize: function() {   
        this.listenTo(this.model,'change:options', this.render);
    }
});

app.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    defaults: {
        //options
        foo: 'bar',
        //....
    }
});

var newModel = new app.Model();

this.offermenu = new app.OfferMenuView({model: newModel});
```

view -> listenTo (model)

you can see this page: `http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo`

```
view.listenTo(model, 'change', view.render);
```